# Curious what "positive question record" means"?

Tags: discussion

[image]

So I think this box tells me I've got the 5 well received questions I need for this badge.   "Well received" means questions with positive vote totals?  But I'm guessing I don't have "a positive question record" because I haven't received the badge.

What does a "positive question record" mean and how to figure out what mine is?  Or is there a different reason I haven't received the Curious badge?

Comment: Positive question record means your total number of closed, deleted, or negative score questions must be less than half of your total number of questions. The tricky part is that each criteria (closed, deleted, or downvoted) counts **separately**, so one question can be three points against you.

Comment: ah so that's why that badge is fairly difficult to get.. only like 129 awarded.  Thanks.

Comment: Any downvoted question?  or just the questions with a total negative score?

Comment: Total negative score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a question on the main SE [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) site titled [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397).

One of the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399)s to that question explains the concept of Positive Question Record in detail:

> A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions ≥ 0.5`.

---

As @Semaphore noted in the comments above, the answer also makes the point that

> Questions that have been downvoted and closed and deleted count three
>   times in this calculation!